# Suppose $A$ is an invertible matrix. Is it true that there always exists a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $A^{-1}=P(A)$?

Tags: matrices, contest-math

Suppose $A$ is an $ \times n$ invertible matrix. Is it true that there always exists a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $A^{-1}=P(A)$?

The question is from Moscow Institute of Physics and Technology

My attempt: Clearly the characteristic polynomial does not work here. But other than that, I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is true that $A^{-1}$ when $detA) \neq 0$ and in general any power, positive or negative,  of $A$ can be written as a linear combinations of $I, A, A^2, \cdots, A^{n-1}$

the characteristic equation $det(A - xI) = (-1)^n x^n - trace(A) x^{n-1} + \cdots + det (A).$ since $A$ is invertible $det(A) \neq 0.$

the cayley-hamilton theorem states that $A$ satisfies its characteristic equation. therefore, $$A^n - trace(A)A^{n-1} + \cdots  + det(A) I = 0  $$which implies $$A\frac1{det(A)}\left(A^{n-1} - trace(A)A^{n-2} + \cdots \right) = I = Ap(A)$$ where $p(x) = \frac1{det(A)}\left(A^{n-1} - trace(A)A^{n-2} + \cdots\right)$

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Then, considering $I, A, A^2, \ldots, A^{n^2}$ as elements of the $n^2$-dimensional vector space $M_n(k)$, we see that there must be a linear relation
$$
a_{n^2}A^{n^2} + \ldots a_1 A + a_0 = 0.
$$
(Cayley-Hamilton gives you this and in fact something stronger, namely that there is a polynomial of degree $n$, of course, but we don't need this.)

Multiply this polynomial by $-A^{-1}$ and divide by $a_0$ to get
$$
A^{-1} = -\frac{a_1}{a_0} -\frac{a_2}{a_0}A - \ldots - \frac{a_{n^2}}{a_0}A^{n^2-1}
$$
as desired.